# Given a presentation $\langle x, y \mid x^n = y^2 = 1, xy = yx^2 \rangle$, what can we say about the order of the group?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Given a presentation $\langle x, y \mid x^n = y^2 = 1, xy = yx^2 \rangle$,
we know that there is a implicit relation,
since $x = xy^2 = (xy)y = (yx^2)y = yxyx^2 = y^2x^4 = x^4$,
thus $x^3 = 1$,
this shows that the order of $x$ is less than or equal to $3$.

My question is if we let $n = 3k$, what would be the order of $x$?
Under this condition can we conclude that order of $x$ is equal to $3$?

Comment: Do you know the universal property which describes the set of homomorphisms from a group presentation to another group?

Comment: I rolled back your edit to the question for two reasons. Firstly, the answers make direct reference to the original version of your question ("Yes, the order of $x$ is $3$ if and only if $n$ is a multiple of $3$."). Secondly, the edit essentially removed all the effort/context from the question, and would therefore be closed, which we want to avoid :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the order of $x$ is $3$ if and only if $n$ is a multiple of $3$.

First, if the order of $x$ is $3$, the fact that $x^n = 1$ implies that $3$ divides $n$.

Now, suppose that $n$ is a multiple of $3$. You showed that $x^3 = 1$ in this group, so the order of $x$ divides $3$ – we must only show that the order of $x$ is not $1$ (i.e. that $x \neq 1$) to conclude that the order of $x$ is $3$. To see this, note that by universal property, there exists a homomorphism from this group to $S_3$ which sends $x$ to $(1 \; 2 \; 3)$ and $y$ to $(1 \; 2)$. In particular, $x$ is not sent to the identity element of $S_3$, so $x \neq 1$, as desired.

Edit: I'll include a quick description of the universal property I mentioned.

Let $G = \langle X \mid R \rangle$ – $X$ is the set of generators in the presentation, and $R$ is the set of relations in the presentation (every equational relation in a group presentation can be written in the form $\text{something} = 1$, and it is this $\text{something}$ that we call the relation and put in the set $R$). In your example, $X = \{x,y\}$ and $R = \{x^n, y^2, xyx^{-2}y^{-1}\}$. Let $F = \langle X \mid \varnothing \rangle$ be the group presentation with the same set of generators and no relations, a.k.a. the free group on the set $X$.

**Theorem 1.** (Universal Property of Free Groups)
For each group $H$, each function $f : X \to H$ extends to a unique homomorphism $\overline{f} : F \to H$.

This is exactly like how a linear map between vector spaces is uniquely determined by what it does to a basis – once you decide on a function (any function) from the basis to the codomain, it extends uniquely to a linear map (a.k.a. vector space homomorphism) from the domain. This is actually quite easy to prove – you should try to do so, and even if you don't it's important to think through this and understand how $\overline{f}$ must be constructed (or else you will be lost later on). Now we can generalize this to a similar statement about all group presentations:

**Theorem 2.** (Universal Property of Group Presentations)
For each group $H$, a function $f : X \to H$ extends to a unique homomorphism $G \to H$ if and only if $\overline{f}(r) = 1$ for all $r \in R$.

As mentioned previously, Theorem 1 is a special case of Theorem 2 where $R = \varnothing$, although (at least the way I wrote it) we needed the result of Theorem 1 to write Theorem 2 concisely. This is harder to prove, because you have to be very careful about defining the map $G \to H$ and proving it's a homomorphism. If you want some practice proving something nontrivial directly from the definition of "group presentation", this is a good exercise. Anyway, we can apply this in your example to produce a map from your group to $S_3$:

Let $f : \{x, y\} \to S_3$ be the function which sends $x$ to $(1 \; 2 \; 3)$ and $y$ to $(1 \; 2)$. We see that
$$\overline{f}(x^n) = (1 \; 2 \; 3)^n = ((1 \; 2 \; 3)^3)^k = 1^k = 1,$$ $$\overline{f}(y^2) = (1 \; 2)^2 = 1,$$
$$\overline{f}(xyx^{-2}y^{-1}) = (1 \; 2 \; 3) (1 \; 2) (1 \; 2 \; 3)^{-2} (1 \; 2)^{-1} = (1 \; 2 \; 3) (1 \; 2) (1 \; 2 \; 3) (1 \; 2) = 1.$$
Thus, there is a unique homomorphism $\langle x, y \mid x^n = y^2 = xyx^{-2}y^{-1} = 1 \rangle \to S_3$ extending $f$.

Comment: Can you clarify why the order of $x$ is $3$ if and only if $n = 3k$?

Comment: My understanding is that the order of $x$ must divides $3$,hence it is $1$ or $3$. When $n$ is not multiple of $3$, the order of $x$ can not be $3$, hence it must be $1$ and the group will "collapse". is this correct

Comment: That's correct – this is exactly the contrapositive of the argument I gave for the forwards direction. The other direction is more complicated – we need to show that $x \neq 1$, which means we need to show that there is no way to derive $x = 1$ from the relations $x^n = y^2 = xyx^{-2}y^{-1} = 1$. (1/2)

Comment: This kind of thing is *very* hard to do directly by just thinking about the relations (indeed, it's not even always possible to do: read up on the "word problem" if you're curious). Instead, to understand group presentations, you really need to understand the homomorphisms from them. These are described by the relevant universal property, which you *must* learn if you want to be proficient with group presentations, even if you don't want to phrase it in terms of category theory. (2/2)

Answer (score 2):

We can "straighten" any word in $x$'s and $y$'s into the form $y^a x^b$ by moving any $y$'s to the right of $x$'s left. As you've noted, $0 \leq a \leq 1$ and $0 \leq b \leq 2$, so the group has size 6 at most. Indeed, your group with $n=3$ is one of the usual presentations of the dihedral group of order $6$, where $x$ is the order-three rotation of a regular triangle and $y$ is reflection. The same clearly holds when $n=3k$. When $n=2$, your group should collapse down to the cyclic group of order $2$, $\langle y \mid y^2 = 1\rangle$.

Comment: When $n$ is divisible by $3$, this is always $S_3$, whether $n$ is even or not.

Comment: @SteveD Thanks, fixed.